# React-scripts not recognising third party jsx in a npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have a react app that was created using create-react-app from facebook. I have referenced a third party private npm package from my create-react-app project. The third party package has es6 and jsx syntax components.

When I start my app react-scripts won't compile the node modules.

Is there any way to get get a create-react-app project to recognise jsx and es6 from an external module, without exporting the entire app and modifying webpack?

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/third-party-package/src/web/testComponent.js
Module parse failed: \node_modules\third-party-package\src\web\testComponent.js Unexpected token (8:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {
|     return (
|       <div>
|         Test component text
|       </div>
```

Comment: You might need to match the webpack/build setting if you importing a non-built react component. Do you have the build requirement list of that npm package?